# Java-spingboot how to save text document via REST-API?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am a beginner programmer, help with the implementation of uploading a text file  via rest-api java.

I have already implemented the simplest action - unload a file from the server, here is my code:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/file/{filename:.+}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> unloadFile(@PathVariable String filename) {
    Resource file = storageService.loadAsResource(filename);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION,
            "attachment; filename=\"" + file.getFilename() + "\"").body(file);
}
```

I can test the file unload by simply following the link!
I cannot test the upload. I find it difficult to write tests. Please tell me if I got a working code and maybe there is a better way to upload. My code upload:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/file")
public ResponseEntity<MultipartFile> uploadFile(MultipartFile file) {
    storageService.store(file);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(file);
}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you just want to upload and download the text files using Spring Boot ?

Comment: @AmitMishra Yes! It's my studying test

Comment: I would love to help you with that let me gather some info and I will get back to you :)

Comment: Your code is fine and it should work, you can try running the application once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload the file/files using spring boot application we use same method that we had for servlet containers. In your controller

```
@PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String fileName = yourStorageService.storeFile(file);

        String  = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath()
                .path("/downloadFile/")
                .path(fileName)
                .toUriString();
//You can even generate download links.
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(HttpStatus.Ok, "Uploaded", fileDownloadUri);
    }
```

To download the files:

```
    @GetMapping("/downloadFile/{fileName}")
        public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName, HttpServletRequest request) {
            // Load file as Resource from DB or local
            Resource resource = fileStorageService.loadFileAsResource(fileName);

return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(resource);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For @PostMapping(value = "/file") endpoint , its best to return a success/error status  instead of returning the file,if file is larger ..it takes time to return back.

Better to return success state. 200 ok.